# Replace * in css?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm using a plugin in my project, what requires the following code in it's css file:

```
 *,
 *:after,
 *::before {
     -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
     box-sizing: border-box;
 }
```

The problem is that this screws up my whole site, is there any way to replace it with something more targeted?

Thanks

Comment: Does this plug in have a specific HTML markup? Or specific CSS classes?

Comment: it changes your box layout, so if you had a layout that was fine looking in `content box model`, it can look weird now..

Comment: What kind of project is this?

Comment: what is the name of the plugin?

Comment: Any reason you're mixing single-colon and double-colon pseudo-elements (`:after, ::before`) in the same selector? If you're going to use one or the other, stick to it. The point of having double colons is so you only use single colons for pseudo-classes to avoid confusion.

Comment: Just a note, I have `box-sizing: border-box` set on everything as part of my CSS reset. It makes things generally more intuitive, so I suggest you try it on newer projects!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I'm using a plugin in my project*

Wrap the plugin markup inside an container element, like say `div` and assign a class say

```
<div class="my_plugin">
  <!--Plugin Markup goes here-->
</div>
```

Now simply use the selector below to target the element specifically

```
.my_plugin *,
.my_plugin *:after,
.my_plugin *::before {
     -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
     box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

The above selectors will simply select **ALL** elements which are nested inside `.my_plugin`

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/eyznx/)

Answer (score 0):

Change `*` to specific element.  For example,

```
html, body {
}
```

or **override** it using

```
class (dot) or 
id selectors (#).
```

Answer (score 0):

`*` targets each and every element. To go around it use class or div of the element you want to target like so:

```
 .my-div,
 .my-div:after,
 .my-div::before {
     -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
     box-sizing: border-box;
 }
```